# Creating a Windows service in delphi

Tags: delphi, windows-services

I have created a windows service in delphi. My code is run within ServiceExecute

```
procedure TMyService.ServiceExecute(Sender: TService);
 while not Terminated do
 begin
      CallSomeProcedure;  
      Sleep(1000);
      ServiceThread.ProcessRequests(false);
 end;
end;
```

Unfortunately, I can not get this code to run. I doesn't seem to call the procedure even when I'm debugging.
The code in Myservice.exe looks like this.

```
begin 
    if not Application.DelayInitialize or Application.Installing then
       Application.Initialize;
    Application.CreateForm(TMyService, MyService);
    Application.Run;
end.
```

I can get the serviceExecute to run if I add

```
MyService.ServiceExecute(nil);
```

into MyService.exe however if I install it as a service it appears not to be running as Application.Run does nothing

Not sure what I'm doing wrong, but any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Nothing there looks wrong to me.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You cannot just run the service from the IDE to debug it; in that case it will just exit. The service has to be started by the service control manager. Also, you shouldn't be calling ServiceExecute directly.

Here's [documentation](http://docs.embarcadero.com/products/rad_studio/delphiAndcpp2009/HelpUpdate2/EN/html/devwin32/idh_debuggingservices_xml.html) how to debug services.

Comment: Thanks for the quick responce. I have got it to debug now and I'm just having problems with the ADOQuery that I'm using. Should be able to fix the problem now I can debug. Thanks

Answer (score 5):

If you've created a service, you can install it by running it with parameter `/install`

After that, the service should show up between your other services (go to `start/run/` and enter `services.msc`).

You can then start it, and you can debug it by attaching the debugger to it.

However, it's painful to work like that. I can't believe that some people actually work like that. I usually have all my business logic in separate units that I can run from a "normal" application. Only when that works out good, I wrap it in a service and try that.

Sometimes I even create an application that can run both as a service or with a GUI. You can simply instantiate your service class. You just need to start it yourself, but it'll be a lot easier to debug.

Answer (score 1):

There is [commercial solution](http://www.aldyn-software.com/svcom.html) that was developed specifically to simplify service debugging process. You can [debug your code](http://www.aldyn-software.com/examples/001-SimpleService/index.html) directly from the Delphi IDE, including service's OnStart event.

Comment: svCom is a lot more than just debugging.  Its a whole service framework of its own as a replacement to TService.  In my TService projects, I simply put an `IsDebuggerPresent()` loop at the beginning of the OnStart event handler, and then attach the debugger to the service process once the SCM has launched it.  Works fine.